# How to get the clicked LinkButton text in GridView to a label in Popup Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I am using a **modal popup** inside a GridView for a LinkButton.

what i need is to use the **value of clicked LinkButton** to appear on a **label** on **Popup panel**
[image]

Comment: Could you please post the code you use to display the popup after the user clicks the hyperlink?That will help the community in answering you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"> 
    <Columns><asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Text='<%#Eval("empname") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField></Columns> 
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="LinkButton1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="lnkDummy" PopupControlID="Panel1"> </asp:ModalPopupExtender> 
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="164px" Width="284px" BackColor="#CCCCFF" ><br /><br /> 
          <center><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br /><br /> 
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Do"/></center>
    </asp:Panel>
```

code

```
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton Lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        Label2.Text = Lnk.Text;
        LinkButton1_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Vinod.The way I understand it is that you want to display the value of "empname" in Label2.Text and the code you have posted appears to be doing exactly that.Could you please explain what problem you're experiencing?When you click on the link what is shown in the Label2.Text?Also have you tried debugging?What is the value of Lnk.Text?I've tried this on my side and it works fine

Comment: Hi Deni the problem is solved an the code i posted is the working one earlier i extended modal popup to the linkbutton inside the gridview so the command source was panel that was my mistake,now its fine any way Thank you Deni

Comment: Great, I believe you can mark your own answer as answered in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkButton btndetails = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
```

you can now access the btndetails text where u wish to show.

Comment: when using the modal popup the command source is panel,so we cant use the above code.

Comment: then get the child of the sender or you can simply use findcontrol from your grid like LinkButton lbtnSetHidden = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbtnSetValue");